# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar campos de dos modelos diferentes?

Tags: python, odoo

Tengo el campo Precio de venta (list_price) del modelo product.template y el campo cantidad (amount) del modelo account.tax.template. 
Quiero multiplicar esos dos campos en una vista: product.template.product.form
¿Cómo prodría hacerlo?

```
class product_model(models.Model):

    _name = 'product.template'
    total = fields.Float(compute='_total', store=True)

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('list_price')
    def _total(self):
        for r in self:
            test = self.env['account.tax'].search([])
            rec = test.campo['amount']
            r.total = r.list_price * rec


class tax_model(models.Model):

    _name = 'account.tax'
    amount = fields.Float(string='iva')

    @api.multi
    def read_ut(self, cr, uid, ids):
        rec = self.browse(cr, uid, 1)
        var = rec.amount
        return var
```

No me tira ningún error y tampoco me saca el resultado que necesito

Comment: Creo que podrías incluir un campo many2one en tu tabla, en lo cual tendrías acceso a través de ese campo con self.<nombre_campo>.<campo>, donde <campo> sería el campo de la base de datos del otro modelo, y podrías usarlo con un archivo compute para mostrarlo.